# Override span in html css and use TD

Tags: css, html-table, html

I have a span tag inside a `<td>`. In `<td>`, I am setting the font by using the class. However, the `span` has its own font style. I want to override the font styling in the span tag and force the font set in the  tag. I am not sure how to do it, hence please advise.

```
.set_font
{
    font-size:12px;
}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="set_font">
           <span style:"font-size:8px;"> This is a test </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try `!important` in your `<td>` css?

Comment: You have to use "=", not ":" on your style property `<span style="font-size:8px;"> This is a test </span>`

Comment: Yes, I did. I added that in the .set_font{font-size:12px;!important } but it didnt work :(

Comment: Sorry, yes I used = instead of ':'. Sorry, I didnt copy paste the code.

Comment: You've placed `important!` after semi-colon which is wrong. Correct method is `.set_font{font-size:12px !important ; } `

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code. I added this: {font-size:12px!important;} It didnt force the 12px but retained the font size in the span tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit: For a better explanation of the issue and solutions for different scenarios, please see Jukka's answer below.*

Original Answer:

In CSS selectors, the one that is the closest to the actual element is applied. So you should be more specific when using selectors to override the style.

In your example the span element has an inline style which is of the highest specificity.

To gain higher specificity then inline style in an outer element you should use *[style]* and *important*.
You can force the one set on td like this:

```
td.set_font [style] {font-size:120px !important;}
```

Here is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfxN2/)

Comment: Good explanation.  Upvoted because you were the first to clearly  describe the need to change the CSS selector _and_ use !important.  Also, thanks for using a bigger difference in font sizes than 4px in your example :)

Comment: :) I'm happy to be of help.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I am not able to follow completely

Comment: On what exactly you want more information? I think it is clear.

Comment: Should I use [style] in the css? I have not seen this before, hence needed more help.. Thanks!

Comment: Although the fix works, it is unnecessarily complicated (you can use just `td.set_font span` as the selector), and the explanation is wrong. Specificity has nothing to do with the issue; the selector `td.set_font` does not match the `span` element at all. And `!important` does not affect specificy either. It is needed because you *cannot* beat the specificity of a `style` attribute.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Please read the question and see that OP wants to set style of td __without__ indicating *span* element to the *span* element. If the OP would have let us use "span" selector, than you would be right. Besides specificity has something to do with this issue because of the reason above (don't use span selector). And !important affects specificity of style directly (not selector).

Comment: @1.44mb, the `span` element is there, so of course it can be used in a selector. Check the specs: `!important` never affects specificity, it operates at a different level (and specificity *only* depends on a selector, not on anything inside declarations).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela What if it is a dynamic content which can be other elements such as _p_ or _a_, etc. Just like the case of OP. Please read the question again, OP insisted on _not_ using *span* selector. !important is another issue that *must* be used in some cases (such as this one). And yes, it doesn't indicate specificity of the selector it was used in.

Comment: @1.44mb, there is nothing in the question that even suggests that the selector should not contain `span`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela There **was** when this answer was posted. Please check the first revision of the question for proof. And secondly please see OP's comment on Iqbal's answer, it is another proof that original question was asking not to use span.

Comment: @1.44mb, no there wasn’t. There has been only one edit, and it was technical and nothing relating to this. The comment, in addition to being just a comment and not an edit of the question, just says that he cannot add anything to the `span` tag—a completely different issue.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Click edit on the Q and see the first revision for yourself. Here is OP's sentence: "I want to override the font styling in the span tag and force the font set in the <td> tag." I didn't say there has been more than one edit. I said see the original question. And here is the OP's comment on Iqbal's answer: "I cannot add the css to the span tag". He says he cannot add css (not 'anything') to the span tag as the comment of what? Guess what? To the answer of Iqbal which is the same as your answer. So the OP already saw that answer and found it not suitable **for his situation**.

Comment: That still says nothing about using the `span` selector, and the OP simply misunderstood @Iqbal’s answer.

Comment: I'm out of this argument as it is clear that we are not discussing to find the truth and it came to a point where it is impossible to accept even a simple written statement as it is.

Comment: Hey @JukkaK.Korpela Recently I got an upvote on this answer and saw this argument. I read whole thing again and I think you are right.

Comment: It seems I missed a couple of things in OP's answer and comment which made me think the way I thought. Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 4):

Add following CSS.

```
.set_font span {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot add the css to the span tag, as <span> tags are generated by a third party tool.

Comment: Add that CSS to your stylesheet.

Do not mistake to add "!important"

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same as Iqbal’s answer but with an explanation of the issue (and a correct explanation, as opposite to the currently accepted answer):

When you need override CSS settings made in a `style` attribute, and when you cannot modify the HTML source, you need to write a CSS rule that a) refers to the specific element you wish to style (not its parent) *and* b) uses the `!important` specifier (which should generally be avoided, but cannot be avoided here). The reason is that in the CSS [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade), any CSS declaration in a `style` attribute has higher specificity than anything you can get with a CSS rule in a `style` element or in a linked style sheet. Therefore, the only way to override such a rule is to use `!important`.

Moreover, you need a rule that applies to the element at hand. Setting properties on the `div` parent as you have tried cannot possibly help, since the `span` never inherits a property from its parent when the property has been set on it, in any style sheet.

Thus, for example,

```
 .set_font span { font-size: 12px !important }
```

will enforce (to the extent that author style sheets can enforce anything) a 12px font size on the `span` element. If the `span` element might on occasion be replaced by some other element, you can use

```
 .set_font * { font-size: 12px !important }
```

to make *any* descendant of the cell take the 12px font size (which is something that you should not be setting, but I digress). To make just any *child* (direct descendant) have that size, you would use

```
 .set_font > * { font-size: 12px !important }
```

(with slightly reduced browser coverage).

Naturally, you put such CSS rules inside a `style` element or, better, in an external style sheet linked from the HTML document. None of this requires any change in the HTML markup in the `td` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use a seperate class for the span.

css:

```
.set_font
     {
        font-size:12px;
}

.font2{
    font-size:8px;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td class="set_font">
   <span class="font2"> This is a test </span>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: The style is being generated by an editor in my program.. I cannot change the font in the editor, but want to force the style set it in the td.